# Order of ember-cli preprocessors

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, ember-cli-addons

I'm the maintainer of the [ember-cli preprocessor for java.properties files](https://github.com/willemdewit/ember-cli-java-properties-to-object) to generate a JS file exporting a JSON object with values.
The problem I'm running into is that the file is correctly processed (ES2015 flavored), but that files is not transpiled into ES5.

The generated app.js file contains this statement: `export default {"foo":"bar"}` but that should be transpiled into something like this:

```
define('my-app/locales/en', ['exports'], function (exports) {
  exports['default'] = {"foo":"bar"};
});
```

Is it possible to generate the ES2015 flavored file and after that run the default transpiler to create the ES5 variant?

Comment: Make sure ember-cli-babel is in your dependencies hash in package.json. Also ensure your addon is run before ember-cli-babel by putting 'ember-cli-babel' in the `after` array in package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to define this addon to run before `ember-cli-babel` in package.json.

```
{
  ...
  "ember-addon": {
    "main": "index.js",
    "before": "ember-cli-babel"
  },
}
```